# Loop over rows of a single row to merge rows with overlapping dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, group-by

I have two dataframes with the following framework:

[image]

DF1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'USA','USA','UK','UK','UK'],
                'City': ['NYC','NYC','NYC','London','London','London'],
                'Start_Range': pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-01', '2020-07-01','2022-01-01','2019-01-01','2021-01-01','2023-01-01']),
                'End_Range': pd.to_datetime(['2020-06-30', '2021-12-31','2023-12-31','2020-12-31','2022-12-31','2023-12-31'])
               })
```

DF2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'USA','UK'],
                'City': ['NYC','NYC','London'],
                'Grade_Validity_Begin': pd.to_datetime(['2021-10-01','2023-01-01','2021-10-01']),
                'Garde_Validity_End': pd.to_datetime(['2022-12-31', '2099-12-31','2023-12-31'])
               })
```

DF1 contains the validity of the city across different time slices.
DF2 describes the range of another column called 'Grade' for each country-city combination having its own time slice validity.

I would like to merge these dataframes into a resultant dataframe such that :

1. For start_range and end_range not having a grade in DF2, the rows from DF2 remain blank after merging
2. In cases where the Grade is valid in a time slice which overlaps with a tie slice in DF1, the row needs to be split according to the validity of the time ranges in DF1

Since there are multiple cities and country's present in the dataframe, I have to tried to left merge them and group them on the basis of city and country.

Then to loop over each group and compare the start and end dates. But I am not able to figure it out how this would work.

Thankyou for any tips!

Comment: You must provide a reproducible input, images are not.

Comment: Further to @Mozway, preferably also a reproducible expected output.

Comment: Hello, can you make sure your image data is correct? cuz I don't understand why DF2, beg 1.1.23 and end in 31.12.99 (1999?)
Also there are many possibilities here, so if you don't mind to add a couple examples B,C,D

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I have updated the post with relevant df information and code.